# Adding an external URL to a WooCommerce Category for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Struggling a little with this one, I'm trying to add an external URL to a WooCommerce Category.

I'd like to be able to set the category name, image, order, etc (as you can now) but have a URL override the default behaviour and take the user to an external link.

Any thoughts?

Kindest,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter('term_link', function( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if( $term -> term_id == 120 ) // 120 is the term ID which you want to change
        $url = "http://exapmle.com";

    return $url;
}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Hi Merabiko - thank you for this. Would there be any way to add the url field to the Categories section of Wordpress?

Comment: @Jason Hey Jason :) Please open a new question, if this is not related to your question.

Comment: @Jason if you using ACF its very simple.
add the custom field to the taxonomy
and get its value like that

$url = get_field( 'my_field', 'event_'. $term -> term_id ); //event (custom taxonomy) term ID = 4

Comment: @Mr.Jo This is related.

Comment: @MerabikoGvantseladze Thanks. I do have ACF but I can't see the option to stick it to a category only, only posts or pages.

Comment: @Jason
1. add field to taxonomy http://prntscr.com/mzofoc
2. fill that field in edit term or add new http://prntscr.com/mzoh9b
3. add code in functions.php
`add_filter('term_link', function( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    $customUrl = get_field('custom_url', 'product_cat_'.$term -> term_id); // get term custom url

    if(!empty($customUrl)) // Check if its not empty change url
        $url = $customUrl;
    
    return $url;
}, 10, 3);`

Comment: @MerabikoGvantseladze Thank you so much!

Comment: Fixed it myself I missed the 10, 3 :) Cheers!

Comment: @MerabikoGvantseladze One last question, any idea how to add target="_blank" to this also?

Comment: @Jason i have no idea